# Alinear contenido de footer

Tags: html, css

Necesito ayuda de cómo alinear con css y html:

- 3 p en un footer,
- uno a la izquierda, uno en el centro y otro en la derecha.

> He intentado hacer un **`display inline`** en cada uno y alinearlos con **`text-align.`**

Comment: Que es lo que tienes hecho o intentaste? Podrías ponerlo en la pregunta?

Comment: Tal vez poner tu css y html de tu footer ayude a los demás a ver como lo tienes hecho, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que nos muestras como has tratado de alinearlos, considero que lo mas simple es hacer lo siguiente:

- Al contenedor padre, que en este caso sería tu etiqueta `footer` darle un `display: flex;` eso moverá los elementos sobre el eje horizontal
- Al inicio estarán alineados y pegados uno a lado del otro, para cambiar ese comportamiento, hacemos un `justify-content` con un valor de `space-around` al cual generará un espacio de igual proporción entre los elementos y el primero y el tercero con respecto de su contenedor padre.

Quedando tu código así:

```html
      <style>
        .seccion-final {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .seccion-final__parrafo {
          border: 1px solid;
        }
      </style>
    <footer class="seccion-final">
      <p class="seccion-final__parrafo">Párrafo 1</p>
      <p class="seccion-final__parrafo">Párrafo 2</p>
      <p class="seccion-final__parrafo">Párrafo 3</p>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 235px;"
```